# Fit a curve to a distribution using ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data-fitting

Given a dataframe df:

```
hour <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)

fraction <- c(0.041034790, 0.063627419, 0.098259980, 0.129083665, 0.124113475, 
              0.086460033, 0.027706516, 0.010332713, 0.006020325, 0.005744794,
              0.006674574, 0.006529392, 0.007197982, 0.008230617, 0.011662787, 
              0.012966288, 0.012047173, 0.012051243, 0.011828668, 0.013063874,
              0.015974441, 0.017099757, 0.027717391, 0.029555940)

df <- data.frame(hour, fraction)
```

I am trying to fit a curve to hour and fraction using ggplot. 
It looks like right skewed normal distribution.

How can I fit a best line + formula. That is what I have tried:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = fraction)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(df$hour, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                        max(df$hour, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                        by = 1),
                                    1)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE), color = 'red')
```

Should I extend it to make it something like normal distribution?
Or should I use Gamma distribution here?

Comment: I am not completely sure what your ultimate goal is. but you could use splines. Something like ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = fraction)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(df$hour, na.rm = TRUE), max(df$hour, na.rm = TRUE), by = 1),1)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::ns(x, 7), color = 'red')

Comment: @Koot6133 if it's look like bimodal with 2 bells, how can I fit it?

Comment: this `formula = y ~ poly(x, 4)`?